# Which Hero Types can learn which abilities?

Tags: endless-space

Endless Space has 5 hero types: Pilot, Commander, Corporate, Administrator, and Adventurer.

Which hero abilities are exclusive to which types? Is there a graphic somewhere of the full ability dependency chart? (That is to say, a graph denoting which abilities are unlocked by which prerequisites?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a chart put together by someone on the Endless Space forums:

> Post: http://forums.amplitude-studios.com/showthread.php?6030-Hero-Skills-Tree
>   Chart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/22eAo.jpg

**Pilot**

- Most abilities key off Veteran 1
- +movement on fleet
- +offense and +defense
- +hp regen on fleet

**Commander**

- Abilities scattered everywhere: Assailant 1, Defender 1, 2, Veteran 1-4
- lots of battle actions: +crit on kinetics, +block, destroyed ships survive with 5% hp (!)
- -accuracy to enemy
- +xp from battle
- +offense and +defense
- change assignment every turn

**Corporate**

- Most abilities keyed off Negotiator 1 and 3
- +trade routes and trade route bonuses
- +20% science off Veteran 2 -> Dust Wielder 1

**Administrator**

- Most abilities keyed off Director 1 and 2
- +approval (flat)
- +industry (flat and %)
- +food (flat and %)
- +defense off Defender 1

**Adventurer**

- Most abilities keyed off Veteran 1 > Ground Pounder 1 and Veteran 3
- +money leech
- +blockade bypass
- +science leech
- +melee and +offense
- a few battle actions: +critical on lasers, -defense mods on enemy, illusions

Other notes:

- All classes other than the Adventurer get a special ability based off Dust Wielder 1
- Administrators seem completely overpowered
- Pilots and Commanders seem approximately equal for fleets.  Commander gets better actions, Pilots get better passives.
- Corporate and Adventurers seem underwhelming, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Ah, look at all those goodies hiding under Engine Tuner 1! Thanks, David!

Comment: >>>Corporate and Adventurers seem underwhelming, unless I'm missing something>>>What you missed is that corporate can immensely boost income from trade. My last game i had a trade focused hero in my capital, and with only 6 planets i was making 2000 gold a turn with happiness maxed. They are really really powerful especially if you are going for an economic victory.

Comment: @Draken interesting, good to know

Comment: One thing I didn't realise at first is that you can click on the class in game on the hero screen and it will open up a skill tree. Obviously this only helps if you can see a hero with the appropriate class.